# Finding "words" separated by commas in a single column with the CONCAT_WS() function

Tags: mysql, php

I have a problem when using commas separating distinct values contained in a column. I call a query as follows:

```
$findd = KL123,OTHER123

$query = "SELECT * 
            FROM test1 
           WHERE concat_ws(' ', column1, column2) LIKE '%".$findd."%' 
              OR concat_ws(' ', column2, column1) LIKE '%".$findd."%'";
```

So, I would like to search for words separated by commas with the following value `$findd= KL123,OTHER123` in a table that contains the following data:

```
ID  name  column1    column2
--  ----  ---------  -------
 1  dan   KL123  
 2  lolo  ASI22      OTHER123,KL145
 3  lala  TA123
 4  ttoo  OTHER123
```

But no results "found". I would like to "find" the IDs `1,2,4`.

But if I search without commas the value `$findd= OTHER123` works with the same data shown above, because I "get" the IDs `2,4`

**The question**

How can I solve this task with commas?

My level in MySQL is very basic and I find it difficult to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET("LK123", CONCAT_WS(",", ...))
```

It does require the use of "comma" as the separator, and you cannot have commas in the strings.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Or... **FULLTEXT**

```
ADD FULLTEXT(column1, column2)

WHERE MATCH(column1, column2) AGAINST("+KL123 +OTHER123" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Yes, your app will need to construct this syntax.

Comment: please update the question

Comment: @Eliasayala - Perhaps you meant that you updated the question, and you'd like Rick to see that for further info?

Comment: made another stab